# GitHub pull request conflict when new PR with the same branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

How I can deal with this scenario?

- I crate a new branch
- I make some changes
- Make  PR [example](https://github.com/petvas/PR-TEST/pull/1) (no conflicts)
- squash and merge it
- make some changes on the branch
- Make a new PR [example](https://github.com/petvas/PR-TEST/pull/2) and it has a conflict

the pr is conflicted with the previous version of the branch, what is the good solution to not have conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

You do work in a short-lived feature branch. Once it is approved and merged back to the main line, delete it. For the next feature, create a new feature branch off the current main line.

Comment: the problem we have beta branch for testing, and if it fails, I fix my feature branch and PR again.

Comment: This is a process problem, not a Git/GitHub/PR problem. Un-reviewed and/or un-tested feature branches should not be merged. Merged branches should be deleted, not used for further work.

Comment: Okey I go tit, but it is still not the answer for the question ;) How i mentioned earlier this is part of the testing process, I have this issue when I merge my branch to the testing environment, not to the prod. (this is a good or bad practice is not the part of the original question)